# Keep Popup Window in WebBrowser control instead of a new window

Tags: vb.net, browser

When using the WebBrowser control, is it possible to cause popup windows to
appear within the WebBrowser control itself instead of a new window?

I can't figure out how to get the popup to appear in the same browser window. please help me :)

PS : The language I use is VB

Comment: What language? C# or VB?

Comment: the language i use is VB

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple tabs with WebBrowsers, use this under the "New Window" Event:

```
((WebBrowser)TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(((WebBrowser)
TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).StatusText)

'next input <cancel[IE]>
e.Cancel = True
```

If just a plain browser put this under the New Window Event:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(webBrowser1.StatusText)
e.Cancel = True
```